# How to trap the Window state?

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener, windowstate

I'd a snipped and want to know how to trap it?

```
frame.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener(){
    public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getNewState());//I need to trap this state when it prints 7
    }
});
```

When the instance of frame is visible then after `maximizing` and then clicking on `minimize` button it prints `7`(the state of window). I need to trap that state. Can any body tell me how to do so?
I already know that the `e.getNewState()` will return `7` but I want the name of this state.

Comment: To be clear, you want to "trap" as in "prevent the window from changing state"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check if a window was minimized use:

`e.getNewState() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_ICONIFIED`

For maximizing use: `WindowEvent.WINDOW_DEICONIFIED`

```
if(e.getNewState()==7){//your code goes here}
```

here `7` is the state on `minimizing` when its previous state is `maximized`.