# Getting the state of a window

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the state of a window on Windows. I have to check if the window of word is active or inactive. I don't find any answer to this problem in Google. 
Does anyone knows how to do this or if this is possible at all?

```html
Window activeWindow = javax.swing.FocusManager.getCurrentManager().getActiveWindow();
```

The code above returns always NULL.

Thank you for your answers.

Regards 
Roman

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244172/how-to-trap-the-window-state

Comment: Are you using Swing ? If yes add this tag.

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate as the comment on the answer by artmmslv suggests that this has nothing to do with Swing but Windows applications in general which is nicely answered over there.

Comment: @Ben Thank you so much.. It worked :))

Answer (score 1):

Try to use frame.hasFocus() or frame.isFocusOwner()

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html

Comment: Isn't this just for Java application frames? I need to check if a window of an other programm is active like Word or PowerPoint.